# Yellow tint on monitor - GTX 970

Tags: graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-computer

Now I've seen a lot of posts regarding this issue. The one reason why I can never get the right answer is because everyone is so general about their question/issue. 
So here's the deal.

I have a slight yellow tint on my monitor that goes up the screen not too harsh, is sort of avoidable when I put sRGB mode on my monitor (asus vg248qe). Now I know its not the monitor because I tried a different computer with my monitor, and no problems, Also tried a bunch of other cables with my computer so it is NOT the cables. And now that I know its not cable or monitor related it might be a software or graphics card related issue. (also tried integrated graphics and it was fine.)

I have a Display port cable to my 970. A few things I noticed. Whenever I fire up a rocket league match. Half way through the game, I see a sudden difference on the game, I tab out and then realize my monitor is back to normal. First time it happened I was so happy. Then I was shutting my computer off, and when the screen where it says *Shutting off....* comes up it turns yellow again. (that's when my heart broke) After I turn it on, its back to yellow. I try this a few more times back to back where I open a game and half way through maybe like 2-5 minutes in it reverts back to normal. I dont know if there is a software issue or graphics card. SOMEONE PLEASE HELP

### Specs:

Processor - I7 4790K

Motherboard - Z97 GAMING 5

Graphics Card - MSI GTX 970 4GB

Monitor - ASUS VG248qe

Have had PC for 3 years now. Kept Graphics card clean and inside of computer clean. No issues till this day.

### Few suspicions

-Power supply thermal take 700w bronze, Something with voltage to Gcard?

-Something software related activating yellow screen.?

Comment: From your description (if I read it correctly) you ensure the monitor is fine. When you said you tried different cable, you tried different DP cable from the PC to the monitor and you still see it? Have you tried a different PC, using DP cable - and see if it is still coming up yellow? A possibility maybe your GPU DP port is damaged?

Comment: Yellowish tint means you're missing the blue from the RGB system. An imperfect contact somewhere maybe. Do you see any blue at all ?

Comment: Are you running "nighttime mode" in Windows 10, or f.lux, or another application that tints your monitor orange/yellow in the evening or during low-light to preserve your sight?

Comment: Yeah I tried a different PC with the cable and it worked fine. I feel like it may be the port but when I go images and search up red green and blue it all looks good. I really feel like it is software related. Might have to try putting the card in a different computer and see if it is the card.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 introduces Night Light mode. Previously you could have used any of several software products, the most popular of which is called f.lux.

These applications tint your screen yellow/orange as the ambient light fades or based on the clock and sunset times, with the goal of protecting your vision and aiding in rest and sleep.

You can find the Windows 10 Night Light setting in Settings > System > Display. It can either be turned off and on, or it can be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

YES! IT WAS NIGHT TIME MODE! Thing is it did this even during the day, I think something glitched it out, to be honest. I went on it and it was off, I tried clicking on and off and it worked! No clue honestly why it did this. I really appreciate everyone's comments and recommendations!! also thank you @music2myear !!

Comment: I'm glad this answered your question. The polite thing to do here on SuperUser when a comment ends up being the answer is to reply with a comment letting them know they answered the question and then inviting them to post that comment as an answer which you can then accept. This way they get recognition and points for coming up with the answer.